# autocomplete source depending on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to implement some JQuery to use the Autocomplete UI. I have a drop down list with two options. Actor and Film. Depending on what is selected, I would like the source for the autocomplete input box to be different. Is there anything wrong with the JQuery I have?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#selectType").change(function() {

           if ($(this).val() == "Actor"){
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "nameSearch.php",
            minLength: 2
        });

        }
        else if($(this).val() == "Film"){
            $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: "FilmSearch.php",
            minLength: 2
        });
        }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the autocomplete? The code looks right... Does it work, does it not work? You tell us.

Comment: @HanletEscaño It's just not working. I could get it working for each individual option without the if statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
           //Create widget with default data source
           $("#tags").autocomplete({
               source: "nameSearch.php",
               minLength: 2
           });

           $("#selectType").change(function () {
               // Assign new data source like that :

               if ($(this).val() == "Actor")
                   $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source", "nameSearch.php");
               else 
                   if ($(this).val() == "Film")
                       $("#tags").autocomplete("option", "source", "FilmSearch.php");

              // And what is your 2 conditions are not met?????
           });
       });
```